# Scope variable not updating in view despite $scope.$digest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
.controller('PizzaCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$ionicLoading',
    function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading) {

    $scope.$emit('menu-refresh-request');

    $scope.$on('menu-refresh-response', function(event) {
        console.log("pizza");
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        $scope.items = $scope.$parent.menu.pizze;
        console.log($scope.items[1].price);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
        $scope.$emit('menu-refresh-request');
    };
}])
```

The data all checks out. The correct item information is logged to the console. However, the `ng-repeat="item in items"` directive in my view does not update with the pizza items.

I tried using `$scope.$apply` and `$scope.$digest` inside the event listener, but the console threw an error saying the digest was already in progress.

Also worth noting that this controller has two sibling controllers that have identical logic to this one, except for different sections of the menu. The `console.log("pizza")` statement isn't executed until I click into the state.

Is there a clear reason why my view is not updating?

```
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Updating Menu..." on-refresh="doRefresh()">
<div class="list menu-list">
    <a class="item menu-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="menu.pizza-detail({ index: $index })">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="row" ng-bind="item.name"></h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="list-price col col-15">
                    <h4 class="list-value" ng-bind="item.price"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="list-description col col-85">
                    <p ng-bind="item.description"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see your ng-repeat code?

Comment: This looks suspicious (is it pizza or pizze?), $scope.items = $scope.$parent.menu.pizze;

Comment: Yeah haha this is intentional. The code is correct. Just the DOM which isn't updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution to this problem is that I needed to add a missing closing tag to the `<ion-refresher>` tag.

```
<ion-refresher pulling-text="Updating Menu..." on-refresh="doRefresh()"></ion-refresher>
<div class="list menu-list">
    <a class="item menu-item" ng-repeat="item in items" ui-sref="menu.pizza-detail({ index: $index })">
        <div class="row">
            <h3 class="row" ng-bind="item.name"></h3>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="list-price col col-15">
                    <h4 class="list-value" ng-bind="item.price"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="list-description col col-85">
                    <p ng-bind="item.description"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $scope.$apply try to use $timeout angular service.
The $timeout does not generate error like „$digest already in progress“ because $timeout tells Angular that after the current cycle, there is a timeout waiting and this way it ensures that there will not any collisions between digest cycles and thus output of $timeout will execute on a new $digest cycle.

```
.controller('PizzaCtrl', ['$scope','$state','$ionicLoading', '$timeout'
    function($scope, $state, $ionicLoading, $timeout) {

    $scope.$emit('menu-refresh-request');

    $scope.$on('menu-refresh-response', function(event) {
        console.log("pizza");
        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

        $timeout(function(){
             $scope.items = $scope.$parent.menu.pizze;
        });
        console.log($scope.items[1].price);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
        $scope.$emit('menu-refresh-request');
    };
}])
```